# Shorting the code for update dictionary in python

Tags: python

Is there a shorter version of the current code for counting the occurrences if an element in an array and store it in a dictionary?

```
a = [1,2,2,3,4,5,2,2,1]
dic = {}
for x in a:
    if x in dic:
        dic[x] = dic[x] + 1
    else:
        dic[x] = 1

print dic
```

Comment: yes, use `collections.Counter`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1]
dic = Counter(a)
```

From the docs:

> A [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) subclass for counting hashable objects. It is an
>   unordered collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and
>   their counts are stored as dictionary values.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes

You can use `dictionary.get(key, default)` to get a value of a key, and if the key doesn't exist it gives the default argument.

```
a = [1,2,2,3,4,5,2,2,1]
dic = {}

for n in a:
    dic[n] = dic.get(n, 0) + 1
```